# Unable to check dynamically created checkbox, apply e.stopPropagation() works but showing errors in console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created dynamically checkbox but unable to check it, so I have used `e.stopPropagation()` and it works fine but on browser console it throws exception that:

> Uncaught TypeError: e.stopPropagation is not a function.

```
function test{
    var checkboxes3 = '';
    $.each(I_DATA.userList, function(index, element) {
       checkboxes3 += '<span><input id="vUserLevel1" name="vUserLevel1" type="checkbox" value="' + index + '">' + '<label>' + element  + '</label>' + '</input></span>';
            });

            $("#accordionUser3 div ul span").remove();                  
            $("#accordionUser3 div ul").append(checkboxes3); 
    }
    function onEscalateVocera1() {
        $('#accordionUser3 input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    }
```

Comment: You can’t have `<input></input>`. There’s only `<input/>`. You can use `<label><input/></label>`, though.

Comment: because `each()` does not have an event!!!!

Comment: `stopPropagation` is a method on Events. Here, `e` are indexes of the selected elements, i.e. numbers. Why are you expecting this to work, let alone make sense?

Comment: Where is your event bindings?

Answer (score 1):

first of all - what is this:

```
$('#accordionUser3 input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

?

you're "walking" over all the inputs and what? `e` in this case is not an event.

I'm not clear as to what you are trying to accomplish:

if you want the checkbox to be selected by default - just add `checked` to the html you create like:

```
checkboxes3 += '<span><input id="vUserLevel1" name="vUserLevel1" type="checkbox" checked="true" value="' + index + '" >' + '<label for='vUserLevel1'>' + element  + '</label>' + '</span>'
```

if you want to listen to the checkbox being clicked you should use a delegated listener like this:

```
$('#accordionUser3').on('click','input[type="checkbox"]',function(e){
    var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    // do what you need
});
```

this function will work on all dynamically created checkboxes inside `#accordionUser3` (assuming `#accordionUser3` isn't created dynamically)